# CHMOD in web hosting

Tags: php, security, apache-2.2, unix, chmod

my Hosting is use Apache and PHP

i understand what it's mean `777` in CHMOD or `drwxrwxrwx` or Owner, Group, Public => read, write, execute.

1. i understand with the `RW` CHMOD command but what about the `X`, it for authorization execute the Shell command or my PHP script or both?
2. When we upload the image through browser, let's says in CMS (wordress, joomla, etc) whe have ability to upload image. when we do it, what is the CHMOD we need? since i assume if access via web browser then we are as `public`

sorry for my bad english, i don't know how to explain it's more simple.

Comment: @GusDe CooL - normally we dun need the executable write especially in web environment, in CLI `php -q FILE` will do, same as shell, of course for hardy purpose, we often change it to executable (my 2cents, dun scold me)

Comment: it's preferred to refer to permissions as User, Group, Other (ugo) as it's how you can set permissions with `chmod` (eg. `chmod u+x file`). Since you talk about "web hosting", it's possible that the hosting service already set up the right permission for you so you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP scripts will be executed whether the "X" permission bits are set on the PHP
files or not.  That's because the script itself is not a standalone executable -- it's
just an input file to the PHP interpreter, so "R" permission is sufficient.

For a shell script that starts with a "shebang" line (for example, #!/bin/bash), the "X" permissions will be checked before the OS allows the script to be executed.

For directories, the "X" permission bits are interpreted differently -- rather than
granting "execute" permission, they grant "search" permission -- is that user allowed
to list the contents of that directory?

Comment: The "X" is not checked before the script is executed. The OS does not recognize it as a command if it does not have 'X'. You can always run the script by explicitly calling the interpreter (eg `bash my_script`). The 'X' on directory does not grant 'search', it grants access. To list a directory, you need 'R' permission.

Answer (score 0):

usually what I have is

```
chmod 770 the_folder
```

and

```
chown apache_user:apache_group the_folder
```

and make sure that ftp_user added to apache_group so that you could modify the files usign this command

```
usermod -G apache_group ftp_user
```

hope helps! :)